# How do I change the color of the div targeted as anchor?

Tags: css, colors, hyperlink, anchor

Let me try to make myself clear: I have a menu that, when you click on a link, it jumps down to the content in that same page. In other words, it's just an link that anchors to the content. **Could I possibly change the color of, let's say, the content's h1 tag after clicking on the link?**

I also thought of a different way of solving, but I'm not quite sure: **could I change the color of a H1 tag depending on its position as you scroll down a page?**

Cheers!

Comment: Both of those scenarios are possible with some javascript.  A CSS only solution would be to make use of the `:target` pseudo selector, however support for this selector is limited especially in IE.

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
h1:target {color: red;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the :target pseudo-selector in CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/8rHvy/

See here for the current browser compatibility:
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Answer (score 0):

The CSS3 :target pseudo-selector will do what you want, but if browser support is an issue, you could do something like this:

jQuery

```
$('nav li a').click(function (e) {
    var targ = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html, body').scrollTop($("'" + targ + "'").offset());
    $("'" + targ + "'").css('color','red');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#someElement">Click here!</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```